# How to remove extra semicolons from the end of some lines in a txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to stackoverflow so if my post is not correctly posted or you need more info please let me know. So i have a really weird problem. I have a txt file with a lot of lines separated by ";". Normally there should 42 fields/columns, but for some reason some lines in my txt file when imported and separated by ";" it shows me a large amount of lines that are being skipped because python "expected 42 fields, saw 45". I import the file using pandas as most of my transformation are done with it:

```
text = pd.read_csv('file.txt',encoding='ISO-8859-1', keep_default_na=False,error_bad_lines=False, sep=';')
```

What I found out is that for some lines I have 3 extra ";" at the end. Because most of the data is confidential and I cannot share it outside my company I generated a similar 3 line txt file to show you where my issue lies.

> ;;;5123123;text1;text2;;;;123124;text3;text4;;;;5234234;text5;text6;;;;412321;text7;text8;;;;512312;text9;text10;;;;15123213;text11;text12;;;;123123;text13;text14
>   ;;;4666190;text1;text2;;;;312312;text3;text4;;;;5123123;text5;text6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;55123;text7;text8
>   ;;;5123123;text1;text2;;;;1321321;text3;text4;;;;123124;text5;text6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3123123;512312312;text7;;;

So Those are similar three lines from my file, but with substituted names. The first and second line is correct, but the third yields me 45 fields when imported.
So is there a way that I can go through the file before importing it and look for all lines starting with `;;;5123123` and check if there are ";" at the end and if there are remove them, and after that of course import them. The problem is only with some lines starting with `;;;5123123`. There are a few hundred lines with this error and the whole data is a little bit more than 50k linees.

Comment: How is this data generated? The format is pretty awful to split, is there any way to sort the output upstream?

Comment: Hello it is generated automatically each day from an internal system within the organization that I operate. Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to fix the problem before generating the data. But if I am not mistaken each line has been manually imputed by somebody into the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe pd is pandas, so you can use `usecols` argument for `read_csv` method

```
text = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                   encoding='ISO-8859-1', 
                   keep_default_na=False,
                   error_bad_lines=False,
                   sep=';',
                   usecols=list(range(43)),
                   names=list(range(43)),
                   headers=None)
```

**Edited**
You can also add `names` and `headers` argument

Comment: Hello, the code that you provided me gives an "ValueError: Usecols do not match names." . I am gonna try to see if I can go around this error.

Comment: @soky you can use `names=list(range(43))` argument in this case

Comment: Actually now it works without the names and headers part for some reason, because I wanted to preserve the column names from first line of the code. Thank you a lot! I tried to up your answer, but i have less than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to split into a list and then removing blank elements??

```
f = open('file.txt', 'rb')
raw_str = str(f.read())
full_list = raw_str.split(';')
templist = list(filter(None, full_list))
```

by printing templist it gives a list of all elements. you can perform any action on it like to convert into a string again by using for loop according to your requirement. output is like- 
[image]

Comment: The issue with this is that I need those empty cells (with the exception of the lines that start with ";;;5123123" there I do not need empty spaces after the last text). A  lot of the lines will have some of those columns/cells empty but also a lot will have some information in it. And I want to keep the consistency between each line and the amount of columns it has.